# Does Postgresql 9.2+ includes PK field in other indexes

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I am trying to improve lookup performance. Assuming I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
  id SERIAL, -- PRIMARY KEY
  code VARCHAR(20),
  ....
  ....
);
```

I need to lookup only "id" (PK) values (don't need any other fields from that table) by "code", like this.

```
SELECT id FROM tab WHERE code IN ('a', 'b', 'c').
```

I can create a simple index on "code" as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX tab_code_idx ON tab USING btree(code);
```

I also know that PostgreSQL 9.2+ implements index only scan in cases when that index contains all fields referenced in the query. So my question is this. Will I benefit from creating an index which includes both "code" and "id":

```
CREATE INDEX tab_code_id_idx ON tab USING btree(code, id);
```

I searched and could find any info on whether PK values are included with other indexes on that table. If PK was included in all indexes then I would only need to index "code" in order to look up "id" values.

Comment: Run `explain analyze` on your query and you'll know (but make sure your table is sufficiently large in order to make an index scan worthwhile)

Comment: You are right and I did that. At the moment I am in design phase and the table doesn't have enough real data so the plan shows seq scan. I'll try filling it up with dummy data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a PK is created a corresponding index is created including the PK columns. No other index is created. To show all indexes on that table type at the psql prompt:

```
=> \d tab
```

An index including both `code` and `id` is necessary for an index only scan in that query.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thanks!